# How to stop onfocus event from firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to catch chatbox input field onfocus event to know that user has read the messages. When onfocus event is trigered I will send ajax to server that messages has been seen.

Whatever appproach I try I always get onfocus event constantly firing.

```
<input type="text" name="content<?php echo $id; ?>" placeholder="Type message..." onfocus="chatboxInputInFocus(<?php echo $id; ?>)"/>
```

and JS:

```
function chatboxInputInFocus(swap_id){
    alert(swap_id);
    return;
}
```

What I get is constant alert. How to catch only the moment when input comes to focus? JS or Jquery.

Comment: are you open to using jquery or vanilla js only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `alert()` for debugging, as it triggers your focus.
Use `console.log()` instead, and your code will work.

```js
function chatboxInputInFocus(swap_id){
        console.log(swap_id);
        return;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="content123" placeholder="Type message..." onfocus="chatboxInputInFocus(123)"/>
```

Comment: I was just typing that same answer. The issue with alert is, that it after it pops up, focus is brought to that alert and after user closes it, the focus is be brought back to input field. Hence, infinite loop.

Comment: I was just typing that same answer. Here is the issue with using `alert()` for debug: After alert pops up, focus is brought to it and once user closes it, the focus is brought back to the input field. And as he is trying to detect onfocus event, he will get the infinite loop. *(fixed the typos)*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the handy `.one` method of `jQuery`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").one('focus', function(){
        alert('Just once!');
    });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: That function is handy, but its not really the correct way to do what he wants. People should avoid `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: That isn't his issue though. The event keeps firing. Using console only masks his actual problem even if it's the proper way to debug.

Comment: But his event keeps firing because he is using `alert()`, if he didn't use alert he wouldn't have this problem... Look at my comment under second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Need here to pass the event object in the onfocus function param and do the preventdefault.    `function chatboxInputInFocus(swap_id){
    alert(swap_id);
    ev.preventDefault();
    return;
}`
 onfocus="chatboxInputInFocus(event,id)"
`